# Except linking object files of current code and other included header files, what other task linker do?

Tags: c, compilation, linker

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<a.h> // other file which have function "fun()" declaration
int main()
{
   int a  =100;
   
   printf("print fun = %d", fun());
   return 0;
}
```

Except linking object files of current code and other included header files, what other task linker do?
see below dummy code:

Comment: sorry, I really don't understand the question

Comment: included header files are not linked, header files are dumped to your *.c file in compilation time. You can check out  your final *.c file by using '-E' flag

Comment: See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to linked programs (e.g., C, C++) , as opposed to interpreted programs (e.g., shell scripts, most byte-code languages, interpreters). The shades of grey for byte-code languages are ignored here.

Linkers start by collecting the object modules (called .o files herein) and libraries the command line points it to, building a list of all provided and referenced global names therein. By this time the actual source code has been left behind. Ignoring debugging information, described later, effectively only the names of global variables and functions remain in .o files along with associated values.

The object code tracks what parts of .o files are variables and what parts are executable code along with the names and locations of external entries.  Some languages (C++) track argument signatures though others (C) do not.

Keeping it simple, after including .o files on the command line in the build, the linker's major job is to look through those .o files to extract references to all externals and then hunt through the libraries to satisfy those externals. The whole lot is bundled up into your executable or, in the case of dynamic libraries loaded during execution, appropriate links to loadable modules are put in the executable.

The linking process assigns everything linkers put into executables a memory addresses to reside at. The linker puts all this into the executable along with additional metadata, such as file headings and optional debugging information, in a way loaders can nicely extract when the program runs. This is usually divided into program segments for executable code, data segments when the program's variables that have initial values associated with them live, and places for variables that have no specific values live that get the default value of binary zeros. These segments provide the run time layout of the executable.

A few basic things, like the names and locations of functions, are often kept in all builds, but this can be so minimal to be worthless in debugging most failures, which leads developers into using -g during development in most POSIX/Linus type compilers.

Debugging information for .o modules compiled under -g (or whatever) will be discarded if the linker is not told to keep it in the build. This information includes all of the external variable names, functions, their addresses, and more; all that stuff you can see with debuggers is included here, and adds considerable to the size of executables. This often includes associating locations of functions, and code therein, to the original source files.

Linkers also identify where the execution is to start at. A small but critical thing and is not the "main()" type functions that beginners tend to believe is the start of their code's run but some place deep with the language library that is automagically included into the build in perhaps obscure ways. This startup code assures all the stuff needed for successful execution happens, like getting ready to handle malloc(), use inherited open files, setting up environment variables, setting up the stack and heap, and the like. Once all this is done main()'s code is used to kick off the user's code. While the linker has nothing to do with this initialization code, nor the final completion code that runs when the program exits or the main returns, the linker does point assure this start up code is present, which also includes properly exit when user code is done.

Once built the linker is done, with the big exclusion of possibility handling dynamic modules that get loaded when called. How such are handled are heavily dependent on the OS and the nature of the link. Sometimes a linker can be involved and sometimes it is "just" loading a module file.

In my view the "loader" that reads in executables into the proper memory, zeros out some chunks of memory, and other start up handling, as a key partner with the linker. While a key partner it is definitely a separate program.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, the linker *links* object files (the result of compiling your various source code files (*not headers*), the standard library, the math library, the ncurses library, the big integer library, ...) and adds management data to make a recognizable executable (ELF format, EXE format, PE format, ...).